# How can I conditionally display HTML in a button using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like for a certain button element to contain plain text by default, but then contain HTML based on some variable in my Angular scope. My goal is to have the button say "Save", but then become disabled and display a loading wheel when clicked (while awaiting a response from a long AJAX request). The problem is, Angular is displaying the literal text of my ternary operator in the button rather than the result of the expression.

Here's what my button looks like:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
  {{ IsLoading === false ? "Save" : "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'></i>" }}
</button>
```

[image: Broken Angular code in button]

When I change the HTML to just some plain text (for instance, "Loading..."), then it works fine.

How can I get it to display the *result* of the expression rather than the text of the expression itself? Thanks.

*Side note: [I tried to get a demo up and running](https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/7uyuvpyf/), but it seems that I can't figure out how to wire up the Angular properly using JSFiddle. This is not the purpose of my question, but I'd really like to know where I'm going wrong so I can successfully make simple Angular demos in the future. Any advice is appreciated.*

Comment: If your wanting to spin whilst loading from a $http then have a look at http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-busy this uses the promise pattern. It will also disable the bits that child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7m2bqo9/2/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoadingController">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
      <span ng-if="!IsLoading">
        Save
      </span>
      <span ng-if="IsLoading">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>
      </span>

    </button>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
     <span ng-if="!IsLoading">
        Save
      </span>
      <span ng-if="IsLoading">
        Loading...
      </span>
    </button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller('LoadingController', function   LoadingController ($scope) {
    $scope.IsLoading = false;

  $scope.OnClick = function() {
    $scope.IsLoading = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $scope.IsLoading = false;
    }, 1000);
  };
});
```

note:Angular 1.1.5 added a [ternary operator](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b) support, and your fiddle pointing to older version, that's why its not working

Comment: Brilliant -- thanks! Side question -- any idea why the `setTimeout` in my OnClick event isn't working? Not essential, just curious.

Comment: check this out [link](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq/angularjs-use-timeout-not-settimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your i element in an div with the ng-show or ng-hide element and then apply your expression to the value of either of those two directives.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to google about the following 3 things which will serve your needs in any way. You will easily find it

- ng-if
- ng-show
- ng-hide

ng-hide & ng-show will just play around by switching the css display property while ng-if will only add the html in case required condition equals to true.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="flag" ng-init="flag= true">

<div ng-if="flag">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Hello mate.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Angular way" would by this

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
  <span ng-hide="IsLoading">Save</span>
  <i ng-show="IsLoading" class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'></i>
</button>
```

But you need to actually load Angular.js in your jsfiddle, i.e. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>`

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ELYDsfIsbeo7sSvub6Nx?p=preview

Comment: You can also select AngularJS using the "Framework & Extensions" drop-down on the JavaScript options menu.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. However, I still can't get my demo to load Angular properly, if you wouldn't mind helping me figure that out. I already had Angular selected in JSFiddle as @JackA. suggested, and I also manually added it to the fiddle. Any reason why it still wouldn't be working?
https://jsfiddle.net/7uyuvpyf/4/

Comment: @JacobStamm The other trick to using Angular in JSFiddle is that you must change the "Load Type" in the JavaScript options from the default of "onLoad" to one of the "No wrap..." options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZRq2xcSz4shK5ZIjLkqp?p=preview)

All codes are in that link. Posted important part code

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
        <span ng-hide="IsLoading">Save</span>
        <span ng-show="IsLoading"><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'></i </span>
</button>
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZRq2xcSz4shK5ZIjLkqp?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rguvZ2Xs4lwl4QhA9Cv0

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.isLoading = false;

  $scope.click = function() {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.isLoading = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
});

</script>

  <style>
    .loadingButton.loading span {
      display: none;
    }

    .loadingButton.loading i {
      display: block;
    }    

    .loadingButton i {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="isLoading" ng-click="click()" class="loadingButton" ng-class="{'loading': isLoading}">
    <span>Save</span>
    <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'>icon</i>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2r7kkfuu/) , Its a working example of what you are asking for

Updating a little code :

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
      {{ IsLoading === false ? "Save" : "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'></i>" }}
    </button>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="IsLoading" ng-click="OnClick()">
      {{ IsLoading === false ? "Save" : "Loading..." }}
    </button> 
  </div>
</div>
```