# check if JS value exists before displaying HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

I would like to display the following HTML with angular value; ONLY IF the value exists, how could I wrap the below around an if statement, to check if a value exists FIRST, then if it does; display this inner html.

*I'd like to do this inline; ideally with a ternary operator.*

```
<span class="bloCK" ng-mouseover="showPopover()" ng-mouseleave="hidePopover()"><a href="{{website.coolUrl}}" target="_blank">Cool Website</a></span>
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Because this looks more like AngularJS, which is quite different from Angular...

Comment: AngularJS you are correct; sorry for my typo!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally display HTML in a button using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352301/how-can-i-conditionally-display-html-in-a-button-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that "the value" you're talking about is `website.coolUrl`, in which case you can do:

```
<span ng-if="website && website.coolUrl"
    class="bloCK" ng-mouseover="showPopover()"
    ng-mouseleave="hidePopover()">
  <a href="{{website.coolUrl}}" target="_blank">Cool Website</a></span>
```

Update... Oops!

It's only after I posted this that I saw you meant AngularJS, not Angular. I modified my answer for that, but it's been a long time since I did any AngularJS.

Comment: ng-if="website && website.coolUrl" makes no sense, simple ng-if="website.coolUrl" does same. To avoid problems one always prefers ng-href to href

Comment: Since I didn't have all of the particulars of the situation, I couldn't know for sure if `website` itself could always be trusted to be defined. In that case, `website && website.coolUrl` is safer, as it prevents trying to access a property of a potentially undefined value. I'm not sure about AngularJS, but Angular also supports the form `website?.coolUrl` for safe navigation.

Comment: I understand that from Angular point of view it may seem "safer" :) But in AngularJS world template never complains that something is undefined. And it saves you tons of code... e.g. "a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d"